# Docker: Container not reacting to signals

Tags: docker, rasa, containerd

currently, I have a very confusing problem: I am using

- Docker CE 20.10.2 on Ubuntu 20.04LTS
- [RASA v2.6.3](https://hub.docker.com/layers/rasa/rasa/2.6.3/images/sha256-8f06215e632b65aee84a25a0ba14638463dfbc55c5d4a57bf70a73d01e7ff9a7?context=explore) using docker

The container, I am using uses a python script to evaluate messages sent by a user. These messages will simply be parsed using

```py
from rasa.model import (
    get_latest_model,
    get_model,
    get_model_subdirectories,
    unpack_model,
)
import rasa
import rasa.core.interpreter

[... train the model externally and put the model in the directory ...]

model_path = get_model(str(model_path))

core_model, nlu_model = get_model_subdirectories(model_path)
interpreter = rasa.core.interpreter.create_interpreter(nlu_model)

def parse(message)
    return interpreter.parse(message)

# for message in messages: 
parse(message)
# end
```

now, when I let these container images run a few days, and parse some messages, the image just stops working.
I have tried:

- docker stop
- docker kill
- send SIGKILL/SIGTERM

Actually, I can reliably force this container to stop working, when parsing a huge load of messages at once. This will render the container useless after 1-2 Minutes.

the only solution for this is to restart my machine, after which the container works again.

There is nothing in the syslog nor dmesg/kern.log
Has anybody a solution where to look further for errors?

Comment: Does `docker logs <container>` show the last log messages from the container and is there any indication of issues? Is `dockerd` running and can it start/stop other containers? You should be able to restart `dockerd` instead of restarting your machine.

Comment: This is the catch. I have also tried to restart dockerd without success. Docker logs and docker attach works however

Comment: What do the logs show?

Comment: The logs are just normal. As if the container is running. But the process inside does not react to messages anymore.